# Product options not showing up after import products

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

I have paid someone to import all my magento items from our yahoo store and he was able to get them all in there.

The issue I have is that the products show up but no the options. The options are all setup fine in the backend. Also, if I make a change to one of the options and then save the product, the options will show up for just that one product.

Any ideas as to why all the options on all other products don't show up?

Comment: Your service man made a mistake and didn't set some values for the products. Magento uses them different in the frontend as in the backend. So the result is, that in the backend the default is assumed and saving solves the problem. What might work is, just make a mass saving.

Comment: Hmm, what is a mass saving?

Comment: Product Grid > Select all (top left) > Actions > Update Attributes > maybe add something here, which is the same for alle products - or select nothing > Save.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work. I even tried changing the weight to 1 just to see if that made a difference. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your service man made a mistake and didn't set some values for the products. Magento uses them different in the frontend as in the backend. So the result is, that in the backend the default is assumed and saving solves the problem. What might work is, just make a mass saving.

```
Product Grid > Select all (top left) > Actions > Update Attributes > 
maybe add something here, which is the same for alle products - or select nothing > Save.
```

Then you have to debug what the problem is, maybe save one product and diff a mysql dump before and after, then you know what the missing part is and add this. The alternative is, to tell your service provider and let him fix this.

Comment: Sneaky way of doing things. +1.